# Differential equation with integration factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve this differential equation:

$$ydx+(2xy-e^{-2y})dy=0$$

I found $e^{2y}$ as integration factor but when affect this on equation I don't get $M_{y}$=$N_{x}$ (they are not exact)...

> Note
>   : Thank you  LutzL.I made a deadly mistake integration factor equals to $e^{2y}$$/y$

Comment: Could you document how you derived this integrating factor?

Comment: $(M{y}-N{x})/-M=(1-2{y})/-y=(2y-1)/y$ and I got integral from that and used it as exponent of $e$

Comment: Please extend the question with your further calculations. Just post a note of change in the comments. Integration of $(2-1/y)$ gives $(2y-\ln y)$ and the exponential of that is $e^{2y}/y$, as was also found in the answer of Chappers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you multiply by $e^{2y}$, you find
$$ (y e^{2y} \, dx + 2xye^{2y} \, dy) - dy = 0 $$
But this is then
$$ y \, d(xe^{2y})- dy = 0 $$
Dividing by $y$ gives
$$ d(xe^{2y}) = \frac{dy}{y} = d(\log{y}), $$
which you can now integrate up.

Comment: can you explain this line please : y \, d(xe^{2y})- dy = 0

Comment: $ y \, d(xe^{2y}) = ye^{2y} \, dx + 2xy^2 e^{2y} \, dy $. Is that your problem?

Answer (score 2):

$$ydx+(2xy-e^{-2y})dy=0$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}+2x=\frac{1}{y e^{2y}}$$
This is a first order linear ODE, considering the function $x(y)$
$$x=e^{-2y}(\ln|y|+c)$$
As far as I know, there is no closed form for the inverse function.

Answer (score 1):

you can rewrite the differential equation as $$e^{2y}\frac{dx}{dy} + 2xe^{2y} = \frac 1y \to \frac{d}{dy}\left(xe^{2y}\right) = \frac 1y$$  which integrates to $$xe^{2y} = \ln y + C $$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \alpha y dx + \alpha (2xy - e^{-2y}) dy =0$$
 is exact so that $$ (\alpha y)_y=\alpha_yy +
 \alpha $$

$$ [\alpha (2xy - e^{-2y}) ]_x=\alpha_x
 (2xy - e^{-2y}) + \alpha (2y) $$

So if $\alpha_x=0$ then $$\alpha=\alpha(y),\ \alpha_yy + \alpha =
2y\alpha
$$

So we have $$ \alpha = e^{2y}/y,\ xe^{2y} -\ln\ y +C $$